# How can I display a spring boot "test" on the browser and run the Tomcat server on IntelliJ IDEA when I used @GetMapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I don't know what happens. I run the ApplicationTests to see if the Tomcat server is starting at port 8080. When I check the run this message it appears *"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe... Process finished with exit code 0"*.

I want to display a spring boot "test" on the browser. When I type localhost:8080 on the browser this message shows
*"HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.62"*

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA community. I'm curious why Tomcat is not starting on my IDE? What I'm missing? How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Here are my dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Upgrade your spring boot version... 1.4.2.RELEASE is of 2016...in particular if you like to compile on JDK17...

Comment: Ok, @khmarbaise. After I updated the spring-boot version. It will start the Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Running a test will not start the server and serve you with the requests. You need to run your spring application main class from the IDE or if you use maven then you can use the command in your terminal

`mvn spring-boot:run`

Below are some articles you can refer to get started with a simple spring boot application.

1. https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-application
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-basic-application-in-java-spring-boot/

Comment: After I use "mvn spring-boot:run" on my command prompt. What's next? It will start the tomcat server on IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes it will start on your machine. Default port is 8080 if you don't provide anything explicit. Not necessarily have to be from intellij. You can use standalone command prompt

Comment: why it's _"BUILD FAILURE"_? How can I display it on the browser? When I locahost:8080/test it shows this message _"Hmmm… can't reach this page"_